# Reading large strings in c++

Tags: c++, string, cin

When I try to read `string s` with `s.length() ~ 10000` with this code below. My output is 4094. How can I increase input buffer size?

```
string s;
cin >> s;
cout << s.length();
```

Comment: The string size is only limited by your platform architecture.  The `cin >> s;` will read until it encounters a whitespace character (tab, newline, space, return, etc).  Does your input have whitespace characters?

Comment: It's most likely that the 4095-th character is a whitespace character.

Comment: @Eljay No whitespaces. I have n strings each new in a new line

Comment: How are you getting 4K characters into the console?

Comment: @SergeyA: Actually, content of a text file might be redirected to the **STDIN**. From the command prompt: `type sometext.txt | program.exe` or `program.exe < sometext.txt`. My text file contains 5829 characters. Therefore the code above printed **5829**.

Comment: @fpmBelkov newline is considered a whitespace

Comment: @SergeyA a redirection or a pipe can give you "infinite" input without any typing

Comment: @SergeyA it DNA strands. I'm trying to create data structure for them with ropes